# Вылетает npe при включении режима isActive для констрейнты в ячейке таблицы

Tags: ios, swift

У меня есть таблица UITableView. В ней кастомизированные ячейки. У меня есть текстовое поле, которое в одних ячейках скрыто, в других показано. При этом мне надо чтобы оно не только было невидимым, но и чтобы не имело высоты. Я придумал способ - если поле должно быть видимым то я включаю режим isHidden = false для самого текстового поля, а также включаю в констрейнте высоты этого текстового поля режим isActive = false. В таком случае текст полностью видимый и на полную высоту. А когда мне нужно скрыть текст, то я ставлю в этих параметрах true.

При тестировании у меня первые две ячейки должны быть с этим текстовым полем, а в остальных без него. Так вот первые две ячейки нормально отображаются, а когда дохожу до тех ячеек, где у констрейнты высоты текстового поля включается isActive = true, то у меня вылетает приложение и пишет fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Складывается ощущение, что когда в первых ячейках я ставлю isActive = false, то констрейнта становится nil. Почему так происходит и как это исправить? Если делать обёртку if let cell.text_height != nil то получается что некоторые ячейки как надо отображаются, а некоторые нет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можете изменять приоритет:

```
cell.viewConstraint.priority = isViewMustBeHidden ? 999 : 1
```

Когда значение будет меньше, чем content compression resistance priority, то текстовое поле не будет сжиматься.
И в интерфейс билдере для этой constraint установите значение меньше 1000:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Просто меняйте размер. Когда необходимо скрыть - ставьте 0, когда развернуть - необходимый размер:

```
cell.viewConstraint.constant = isViewMustBeHidden ? 0 : 100
```

В случае как Вы пытаетесь делать, нужны дополнительные шаги.

Comment: В том то и смысл, что у меня автоматический размер. У меня должно быть два режима - нулевой размер и автоматический размер. А не нулевой и конкретный размер.

Comment: @cheerful_weasel уточните. Из "включаю в констрейнте высоты этого текстового поля " так понял, что фиксированный.

Comment: У меня для текстового поля задана констрейнта высоты, она имеет размер 1. Когда она активна (т.е. включена), то текстовое поле свёрнуто до размера 1. Когда я её отключаю, то текстовое поле имеет автоматическую высоту (так-как не ограничивается больше констрейнтой высоты). По сути я нашёл решение, убрав weak для констрейнт высот, но меня смущает это решение, я не уверен, что это правильно.

Comment: @cheerful_weasel дополнил ответ вариантом по такому сценарию, опять же, если правильно понял :) По поводу strong ссылки на constraint пока ничего не могу сказать, не приходилось с таким сталкиваться.

Comment: Спасибо. На будущее буду пробовать тогда такой вариант.