# Отображение view из ячейки при нажатии на кнопку

Tags: ios, swift

Привет! Появилась проблема - не знаю даже с чего начать. Суть вот в чем:

Есть VC, в котором находится tableView. Ячейки конфигурирую в отдельном файле (TableViewCell.swift). В ячейке есть Label и еще одно View, которое по умолчанию скрыто.

Вопрос: как сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку во VC значение view из ячейки менялось на .isHidden = false?

Подробнее

---

Код ячейки:

```
import UIKit
import SnapKit
import BEMCheckBox

class TableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

let checkBox: BEMCheckBox = BEMCheckBox()

override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

    checkBox.isHidden = true
    self.contentView.addSubview(checkBox)
    layoutSubviews()
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}

override func layoutSubviews() {

    checkBox.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
        make.left.equalTo(self.contentView.snp.left).offset(10)
        make.top.equalTo(self.contentView.snp.top).offset(20)
        make.bottom.equalTo(self.contentView.snp.bottom).offset(-20)
        make.size.equalTo(CGSize(width: 40, height: 40)) 
        }
    }
}
```

В MainScreenViewController есть кнопка с методом:

```
deleteButtonTapped() {

}
```

Я хочу сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на эту кнопку срабатывал метод и в ячейках отображались чекбоксы, которые изначально скрыты. Нужно как-то поменять их значение .isHidden на false, и, видимо, перезагрузить таблицу или ячейки, но не я не знаю как это сделать :(

UPD 2

---

```
override func layoutSubviews() {


    checkBox.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
        make.centerY.equalTo(self.contentView.snp.centerY)
        make.left.equalToSuperview().offset(20)
        make.size.equalTo(CGSize(width: 20, height: 20))
    }

    postName.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
        if checkBox.isHidden == true {
            make.left.equalTo(self.contentView.snp.left).offset(20)
        } else {
            make.left.equalTo(self.checkBox.snp.right).offset(20)
        }
        make.right.equalTo(self.contentView.snp.right).offset(-30)
        make.centerY.equalToSuperview()
        make.top.equalToSuperview().offset(20)
        make.bottom.equalToSuperview().offset(-20)
    }

}
```

Comment: Нужно больше данных. Если просто показать "здесь и сейчас", то в didSelectRowAtIndexPath для выбранной ячейки меняете что необходимо. Но так если проскроллить, потом вернуться, то все будет в первоначальном значении. Если по-нормальному, то в модели добавляете переменную, хранящую состояние этого элемента для ячейки, при нажатии меняете значение и перезагружаете ячейку. В cellForRow, соответственно, задаете состояние этого элемента. вечером могу пример  набросать. Какой у Вас вариант?

Comment: @VAndrJ , добавил код, который у меня есть. Так, наверно, будет понятнее, что я хочу сделать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Заведите переменную, в которой храните состояние этих view:

```
var isViewHidden = true;
```

В cellForRowAt задайте его нужной view:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    ...
    cell.checkBox.isHidden = isViewHidden
    ...
}
```

При нажатии на кнопку меняйте состояние и перезагружаете таблицу:

```
isViewHidden = !isViewHidden
tableView.reloadData()
```

Comment: Спасибо! Работает так, как задумывалось. 
Но есть небольшой нюанс: я решил сделать так, чтобы при состоянии checkBox.isHidden == true, Label, который находится справа от чекбокса менял свою позицию (сдвигался влево на 20 поинтов) и наоборот. 

tableView.realoadData() тут не помогает - label остается на месте. Подозреваю, что это из-за того, что код констреинтов у меня располагается отдельно от VC с таблицей. Можно как-нибудь это исправить? На всякий случай добавлю код в посте, чтобы было нагляднее.

Comment: @Stormway меняйте размер необходимого constraint в зависимости от состояния. Как раз вопрос в почти как у Вас: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/671696